# Reducing resolution of images in a PDF file with PHP and TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

At our company we need to store scanned PDF files on a PHP based system. Generally most of the scanned PDF files are over-sized because of the images in them are stored at a very high quality.

Using some online convert tools I can reduce the scanned PDF files up to 80% percent without loosing readability. (Means files are compressible)

I use TCPDF to process PDF files but I could not find a straight forward way to reduce image sizes without distorting PDF layout.

Is it possible to achieve this with TCPDF (or any other libraries are welcome)

Please note: I do not create the PDF file. It is done by scanner. I need to compress a PDF file already created with image(s) in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can compress image before create the pdf, like that:**

```
compressedImage($source, $path, $quality); //before create pdf

// Compress image function
function compressedImage($source, $path, $quality) {

            $info = getimagesize($source);

            if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg'){
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

            }elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif'){
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

            }elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png'){ 
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
            }

            imagejpeg($image, $path, $quality);
            return $path;

    }
```

**Or use class from tcpdf like**

```
public  
setJPEGQuality( $quality )
//------------------//
SetCompression( $compress = true )
Activates or deactivates page compression. When activated, the internal representation of each page is compressed, which leads to a compression ratio of about 2 for the resulting document. Compression is on by default. Note: the Zlib extension is required for this feature. If not present, compression will be turned off.
```

Comment: Actually I do not create the PDF file. It is done by scanner. I need to compress a PDF file already created with image(s) in it.

Comment: TCPDF import is under development on php, so you can't do it for now. you can use [fpdi](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) for import and then use function compressor

Answer (score 2):

You can implement two way:

1. you can reduce image size first via [this](https://github.com/bachors/PHP-Image-Compressor-Class) type of library then generate the pdf file. or,
2. You can set image width and height while generating pdf via tcpdf. like following:

```
Image( $file, $x = '', $y = '', $w = 0, $h = 0, $type = '', $link = '', $align = '', $resize = false, $dpi = 300, $palign = '', $ismask = false, $imgmask = false, $border = 0, $fitbox = false, $hidden = false, $fitonpage = false, $alt = false, $altimgs = array() )
```

See the doc [here](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_009/)